# Should a function be used for a coherent procedure that is used only once?

Tags: language-agnostic

I've read that good programming practice claims that one should use a function if a block is to be used repeatedly in a program. But what if you have a procedure with clear conceptual boundaries, but it is only called once. Should you immediately write it in the main code or should you put it into a function and invoke it in the main code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write-once is one reason to use functions.  However, any block of code with clear conceptual boundaries is a great candidate for a function.

The resulting logic flow of your script will be more straightforward and easier to read/debug.

For example, consider you have a database script that runs some basic audits before continuing with the main work.  This happens once in the script, but the resulting logic flow would be:

```
dbConnect()
dbAudit()
...
do main loop
...
```

Nice and clean, easy for others to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a function unless there is a good reason not to. Your code will stay cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that it's completely up to you. I would favor putting it in a function if there is a conceptual boundary unless it's so short that the extra boilerplate makes the code less readable overall.

One thing worth considering about the programming practice you cited: "one should use a function if a block is to be used repeatedly in a program" does NOT imply "one should not use a function if a block is to be used once". That's actually denying the antecedent and is a logical fallacy.

The correct inversion is more like this: If for some reason you are forbidden to put a block of code in a function, then you had better hope the block need only be invoked once (per execution of the function in which the block of code is located). :-)